# RF: S2L Adding some session names next to Download file Name

Tags: robotframework

We have a Report which displays data in tabular format based on criteria. Clicking ON Excel Icon User can get data into excel as well. File Name is Data Reads Status Report.xlsx. We have 6 Search criteria's to automate each time report gives diff data and user can export same into Excel. NOW the issue is while running individual TC's file Name is coming fine. But when we run all of them together then S2L adding some garbage value next to file name. like Data Reads Status Report *TM2OQW*.xlsx.. Due to this below code is failing always. I am using these lines to open the downloaded file and read the content of it.

```
${DownloadDir}=  Catenate  ${DownloadDir}\\Data Reads Status Report.xlsx
${DataFromXlsx}  read xlsx data  ${DownloadDir}
```

This is the Error i am getting

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\banuch\\Downloads\\Data Reads Status Report.xlsx'
```

Not sure how to handle this situation.   Please suggest some alternative to avoid this situation.

Comment: My guess is that your filename has literal double-backslashes in it rather than single backslashes. However, that would only explain the problem leading up to the filename. The first step would be to log `${DownloadDir}` so you can see exactly what's in it.

Comment: I checked it has only single backslashes. There is no such issues

Comment: maybe it's a bug in the xls library you're using. It's odd that the error message shows double backslashes.

Comment: Have you tried using single forward slashes instead?  i.e. C:/Users .... /Data Reads Status Report.xlsx ?

Comment: Issue something else here.. File name is coming as Data Reads Status ReportAHECE2TB.xlsx While downloading. Extra 8 letter char is getting added at the end of file. thats the reason its unable to open the file. IF NO Extra letters then file is getting opened fine.